# TortoiseSvn 1.8 does nothing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-xp-sp3

I have Windows XP 32bit SP3 with Slick-subversion-1.8.3.1-win32.msi.
I installed TortoiseSvn 1.8.2-24708-win32-svn-1.8.3.msi without errors.
I updated previous repository with success (I checked with "svnadmin verify" and reported no errors. "svnadmin --version" shows "1.8.3-SlickSvn-1.8.3" so it's the right version).
Now I have the repository in 1.8 format (it was 1.7).
I have repositories and working copies on local pc (e:\disk\svn-repository and e:\disk\wc respectively).

When I right click any item of Tortoise menu on my working copy, nothing happens. It gives an error before showing the about dialog (wrong argument), it seems doing something for revision graph (but with 100% cpu for too much time for me to wait :P (I have 1100 commits with thousands of files)) and it just do nothing for every other menu item.

I have uninstalled, rebooted, installed, rebooted, several times. I've tried even a nightly build, version 1.8.1 instead of 1.8.2... nothing changed :(

Overlays icons doesn't show and registry is ok (I've done the checks showed on FAQ).
I've only one subversion installed (I uninstalled previous subversion, checking from windows control panel, I've tried to start "svn" on command line to see it fails as espected).

I've tried also to do on the command line:

```
tortoiseproc /command:log /path:e:\disk\svn-repository\myproject
```

and it suddently returns showing nothing... , no errors, no warnings, no dialogs :(

```
tortoiseproc /command:about /path:e:\disk\svn-repository\myproject
```

show the dialog with "wrong argument" (i've translated from italian so it may be a little different the corresponding error message in english :P ) then the dialog "about" shows up, where I found theese info:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.8.2, Build 24708 - 32 Bit , 2013/08/27 19:20:39
Subversion 1.8.3, -release
apr 1.4.8
apr-util 1.5.2
serf 1.3.1
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
zlib 1.2.8
```

I hope someone can tell me I to make tortoiseSvn works again. I've spent all the day long ( it's 4:27 a.m) browsing forums, faq, mailing list, rebooting, installing and uninstalling and I still don't know I to solve my problem. :(

Thank you very much in advance.
(sorry for every english mistake :P )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a problem of firewall. I uninstalled the firewall, reinstalled the firewall and now Tortorise works as expected. Just the overlay icons on the working copy are not visible (inside every file and every folder has its overlay icon) and probably I can fix it with suggestions reported in official FAQ.
There's no error even in About menu item. :O
Note: I've changed a thing in firewall configuration... who knows ;-)
Anyway it works!!!! I hope it can be of help to someone. :)